# Mysql server without password but key auth safe?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ssh, centos

Following situation: I am a little confused. Running MariaDB on CentOS 7, had some trouble connecting over SSH. Noticed I've set a password for my DB user and I was trying to connect with a private key. 
I removed the password ( [...] PASSWORD('') ) and everything is working fine.

Mysql Workbench is connecting with:

- SSH Hostname: *Server-Public-IP:22*
- SSH Username: Dbuser
- SSH Keyfile: /path/to/id_rsa.ppk
- Mysql Hostname: 127.0.0.1
- Mysql Server port: 3306

If I remove the keyfile and try to connect it gives me an error: Bad authentication type. Which is exactly what I wanted.

My website is located on the Server itself and in PHP I am using:

```
$mysqli->real_connect("127.0.0.1","Dbuser", "", "Dbname");
```

To connect. Which aswell works wonderfully. But since I have not set a key file with

```
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY, '');
```

It makes me ask if not everyone could connect with a SSH tunnel to the server. Or is it only possible to connect from the server itself? ( Isn't an SSH tunnel simulating that? )

Mysql privileges for the DBuser are:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'DBuser'@'127.0.0.1'
```

So, is it secure?

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL user `DBuser` is only allowed ip `127.0.0.1` to connect ,
so that you MySQL only allowed where your MySQL database server is located connect it .